# Table in latex and enumeration

Tags: tables, pdftex, enumerate, enumitem

I have written the following code:

```
\usepackage{enumitem} 


\begin{enumerate}[label=\let\textdexiakeraia\relax(\alph*)]
\item 

\item 
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|  }
\hline
N & e  \\
\hline
25 & 0.01 \\
50 &  0.002   \\
100 &  0.0058  \\
200    & 0.04 \\
400 &  0.041 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\end{enumerate}
```

but I want the enumeration to begin with the greek letter (β). How can I get rid of (α)?

Also, if I use the command `\centering` how can (β) remain at the beginning of the row?

So far it looks like this:

[image]

**EDIT**:  [image]

Comment: Please post a working example, not just fragments. But I guess `\begin{enumerate}[label={...}, start=2]` -- but the table looks awful, in my point of view

Comment: Where is `\textdexiakeraia` defined? Can you please always post complete, minimal documents and not just snippets?

Answer (score 3):

The main problem here is to start the list at `beta`, which occurs when the enumeration counter has the value two then, i.e. `\setcounter{enumi}{1}` -- this can be achieved with `start=2` as an option to `enumerate`.

The other stuff here is just for the greek letter output and not really necessary, I added it in order to show that really greek letters are possible (however, there are definitely better ways to do so)

*I won't do further changes to the table → I leave that to the O.P.*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem} 

\usepackage{textgreek}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\greekalpha}[1]{\c@greekalpha{#1}}
\newcommand{\c@greekalpha}[1]{%
  {%
    \boldmath
    \ifcase\number\value{#1} %
    \or
    \textalpha
    \or
    \textbeta
    \or
    \textgamma
    \fi
  }%
}
\AddEnumerateCounter*{\greekalpha}{\c@greekalpha}{5}
\makeatother


\providecommand{\textdexiakeraia}{some font I don't have}

\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}[label={\greekalpha*)},start=2]
\item 
\item   \begin{tabular}[t]{|*{3}{p{2cm}|}}
    \hline
    N & e  \\
    \hline
    25 & 0.01 \\
    50 &  0.002   \\
    100 &  0.0058  \\
    200    & 0.04 \\
    400 &  0.041 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great!!! Thanks... Now if I use the command centering, nothing changes. If I want the table to be in the middle of the page, what could I do?

Comment: Centering does not look nice here, believe me.

Comment: I wrote this code but at the third \item it doesn't print the letter δ just ")". Why is it like that?  I added a picture of the output in my initial post. @ChristianHupfer

Comment: @evinda: Gonzalo Medina asked you about the `\textdexiakeraia` command which is apparently related to a Greek font -- you did not answer that question or improve your own post. That's why I circumvented the greek font stuff and provided the `greekalpha` counter format for alpha, beta and gamma, but not for more -- that's why `)` appears